# Semaphore in C for shared memory can't initialize

Tags: c, semaphore

The command semctl always returns -1 (returns "Fail2" in console). What am I doing wrong?

```
union semun{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short int *array;
    struct seminfo *__buf;
} forsem;
forsem.val = 0;


int sem;
if((sem= semget(key, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT) == -1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail1");
}

if (semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, forsem) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail2");
}
```

Errno writes `Invalid argument`

Comment: When a system call like `semctl` returns `-1` then check e.g. [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) what went wrong. You can get a printable string with [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html).

Comment: I didn't work with errno much. What should I write to get the error form `semctl` ? E: I got it. It's giving `"Invalid argument"`

Comment: Include the header file `errno.h` and check the variable `errno` to find out the error code.
More details here: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_2.html
Once you have it check what the error code means here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semctl.2.html

Answer (score 1):

You make a simple mistake: in

`if((sem= semget(key, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT) == -1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail1");
}`

You should write

`if((sem= semget(key, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail1");
}`

Notice the brackets?

By the way, the error is `EIDRM` because `sem` is 0 in your code, not `Invalid Argument`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! It does not matter. The only thing it's not giving error is for `semctl` with the second argument 0 (number of the semaphore in the semaphore set), if I put 1 or 30 there, it returns -1.